# Pandas Pivot Table Conditional Counting

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a simple dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a','a','a','b','b'],'value':[0,15,20,30,0]})
df
  id  value
0  a      0
1  a     15
2  a     20
3  b     30
4  b      0
```

And I want a pivot table with the number of values greater than zero.

I tried this:

```
raw = pd.pivot_table(df, index='id',values='value',aggfunc=lambda x:len(x>0))
```

But returned this:

```
    value
id
a       3
b       2
```

What I need:

```
    value
id
a       2
b       1
```

I read lots of solutions with groupby and filter. Is it possible to achieve this only with pivot_table command? If it is not, which is the best approach?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

Just to make it clearer why I am avoinding filter solution. In my real and complex df, I have other columns, like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a','a','a','b','b'],'value':[0,15,20,30,0],'other':[2,3,4,5,6]})
df
  id  other  value
0  a      2      0
1  a      3     15
2  a      4     20
3  b      5     30
4  b      6      0
```

I need to sum the column 'other', but when i filter I got this:

```
df=df[df['value']>0]
raw = pd.pivot_table(df, index='id',values=['value','other'],aggfunc={'value':len,'other':sum})
    other  value
id
a       7      2
b       5      1
```

Instead of:

```
    other  value
id
a       9      2
b      11      1
```

Comment: filter before pivot

Comment: thanks @wen, but I was trying to avoid filter.

Comment: If you consider the speed , filter before pivot is faster

Comment: Didn't know that, but in my case I have others columns in df. I cannot exclude rows with filter because of those other columns. I didn't mentioned this in body question trying to make it clearer, but now I see that I was being misleading. I will update the question body, Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Need `sum` for count `True`s created by condition `x>0`:

```
raw = pd.pivot_table(df, index='id',values='value',aggfunc=lambda x:(x>0).sum())
print (raw)
    value
id       
a       2
b       1
```

As @Wen mentioned, another solution is:

```
df = df[df['value'] > 0]
raw = pd.pivot_table(df, index='id',values='value',aggfunc=len)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the dataframe before pivoting:

```
pd.pivot_table(df.loc[df['value']>0], index='id',values='value',aggfunc='count')
```

Comment: Thanks, @zipa. I was trying to avoid filter. I have explained better in the update. Thanks anyway. =]